# Fatal Error: Index out of Range / UIPickerView /Array/ Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uipickerview

My UIPickerView with four components gives me this back when I'm trying to build it. What should I do I mean I made the number Of Rows one Point bigger because in Swift numbers start at 0 but nothing worked....
What is the problem?

```
let componentOne = [1...1000]
    let componentTwo = [1...59]
    let componentThree = [1...59]
    let componentFour = [1...10]
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if component == 0 {
            return 1000
        }
        if component == 1 {
            return 59
        }
        if component == 2 {
            return 59
        }
        if component == 3 {
            return 10
        }
        return component
    }
        
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if component == 0 {
            _ = componentOne[row]
            return "\(1000)"
            }
            if component == 1 {
                _ = componentTwo[row]
                return "\(59)"
                }
                if component == 2 {
                    _ = componentThree[row]
                    return "\(59)"
                    }
                    if component == 3 {
                        _ = componentFour[row]
                        return "\(10)"
                        }
        return nil
                    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is `componentOne` an `Array`?

Comment: Which line of code do you get the error?

Comment: @aheze in this line: `if component == 0 {`

Comment: @Rob yes of course

Comment: Consider that `[1...10]` is an array of **one** range, not an array of 10 integers.

Comment: Okay but how do I set up an Array with 1000 Integers? I would take hours...;)

Comment: @EasyChris Why do you need to set it up, you can use a `while` loop or if it is coming from server then you can get the array automatically. Just use `count` on it as Vadian displayed in the answer below and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that `[1...10]` is an array of **one** range, not an array of 10 integers.

You have to write

```
let componentOne = Array(1...1000)
let componentTwo = Array(1...59)
let componentThree = Array(1...59)
let componentFour = Array(1...10)
```

To avoid those errors don't hard-code the return values of `numberOfRowsInComponent`.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    switch component {
        case 0: return componentOne.count
        case 1: return componentTwo.count
        case 2: return componentThree.count
        case 3: return componentFour.count
        default: return 0
    }

}
```